# Log4j2.xml configuration file not found

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

I have a project where I am trying to get Apache Log4j2 to work for logging in different files. My project is Spring application and I have a configuration file log4j2.xml in the project structure, but when I run the project, either as Spring Boot or as a war from tomcat, no logging seem to happen except the default standard output.

My project structure:

```
-src
--main
---resources
----static
----templates
----application.properties
----log4j2.xml
```

My configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE" monitorInterval="1800">

  <Properties>
        <Property name="logPattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex</Property>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:catalina.home}/logs</Property>
        <Property name="secondary_path">C:/TEMP/logs</Property>
    </Properties>

  <Appenders>

    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
    </Console> 

    <RollingFile name="FileAppenderInfo" fileName="${secondary_path}/stream-info.log" filePattern="${secondary_path}/stream-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" append="true" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${logPattern}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>


    <RollingFile name="FileAppenderError"  fileName="${secondary_path}/stream-error.log" filePattern="${secondary_path}/stream-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" append="true" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${logPattern}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>

    <Logger name="InfoLogger" level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderInfo"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="ErrorLogger" level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderError"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>

  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I have tried looking for a solution but can't seem to find out what is wrong, I have even tried making a new project and implement the dependencies, xml file and tried logging in the code.

My code looks like:

```
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("InfoLogger");

log.info("POST HAS BEEN MADE");
```

Pom file:

```
<!-- Dependency for log4j2 -->

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

I have also tried without using the version tag.

Hope anyone can help
Thanks

Comment: `<Logger name="InfoLogger" level="error">`: you would want `level="info"` here I guess?

Comment: Yeah, I have it actually don't know where it became error from, but it doesn't change anything :/ not working still

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions :

1) Use package name to specify the logger.

```
   <Logger name="com.sample" level="error">
     <AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderInfo"/>
   </Logger>
```

2) Change your code to match logger

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(); // Take the current class name by default

OR

LogManager.getLogger(Test.class.getName()); //Specify class name

Comment: Did not help after testing it, thanks for the suggesions